# Invalid cursor state when attempt to close

Tags: c++, oracle, odbc

I have a large number of INSERT statments to run.  As I run them, I understandably get "maximum open cursors exceeded".

OK Oracle, so I will close the cursors immediately after running the INSERT statements.

```
SQLCloseCursor( hStmt )
```

But Oracle says to this "Invalid cursor state."

Why is Oracle not happy with me closing the cursor?  I tested this same type of query out through a MySQL dsn and MySQL doesn't seem to complain about closing a cursor immediately after an INSERT statement.

edit --

Here is the code that executes the query

CHECK is a function that checks an SQLRESULT and logs error if any returns TRUE if successful, FALSE if failure.  "status()" uses SQLGetDiagRec() to log the rest of the error info.

```
  SQLINTEGER nonquery( char * nonquery )
  {
    SQLINTEGER rowsAffected = 0 ;

    SQLHANDLE hStmt ;
    CHECK( SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hConn, &hStmt ), "allocate handle for statement" ) ;

    if( !CHECK( SQLExecDirectA( hStmt, (SQLCHAR*)nonquery, SQL_NTS ), "execute query" ) ) 
    {
      status( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt, __LINE__ ) ;
    }

    // Get rows affected
    if( !CHECK( SQLRowCount( hStmt, &rowsAffected ), "row count after non-query" ) )
    {
      status( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt, __LINE__ ) ;
    }

    if( ! CHECK( SQLFreeStmt( hStmt, SQL_CLOSE ), "Sql free stmt" ) )
    {
      status( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt, __LINE__ ) ;
    }

    // CLose up.
    if( !CHECK( SQLCloseCursor( hStmt ), "close cursor" ) )
    {
      status( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt, __LINE__ ) ;
    }

    return rowsAffected ;
  }
```

I call nonquery like so

```
nonquery( "sql statement" ) ;
```

So I'm getting:

```
[24000][0] [Oracle][ODBC]Invalid cursor state.
```

At first, (which might be due to an INSERT statement has no cursor?), and later, after many inserts (nonquery is simply called many, many times in a row), I get

```
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a large number of INSERT
>   statments to run. As I run them, I
>   understandably get "maximum open
>   cursors exceeded".

Actually, this doesn't make sense to me - INSERT statements don't use a cursor. Are you sure this is the error you are getting This would explain why you get:

> SQLCloseCursor( hStmt )
>
> But Oracle says to this "Invalid
>   cursor state."

as there would be no cursor.

The fact that MySQL doesn't complain could be due to differences in the drivers. Are they both ODBC 3.0?

**Edit:** Having looked at your code, I have two questions. Firstly, could we see the SQL commands that cause the problem? Secondly, SQLRowCount is a somewhat dubious function - many databases cannot support it for certain query types, and I can see how it might need a cursor itself. Can you try using a version of your function that doesn't call SQLRowCount?

**Edit2:** Think that Alan has identified your problem. You free a statement and then call clopse cursor on it - this is undefined by ODBC. If you really think you need to close a cursor (which I don't) close it before freeing the statement.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-versions.html says the MySQL driver is "Level 1 and Level 2".

I believe my oracle driver must be ODBC 2 http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odbc/index.html 

I think it makes sense that the insert statement should not have a cursor.. but how am I still getting "maximum cursors exceeded"?

Comment: MSDN says that "invalid cursor" is only returned by a 3.0 driver. I would forget MySQL & concentrate on Oracle - can you post a small example that illustrates the problem? You might also want to post the question on a more Oracle-oriented site as I get the impression not too many SO regulars use it - I'm afraid I don't myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're closing the cursor twice:

`SQLFreeStmt(SQL_ CLOSE)` - From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709284%28VS.85%29.aspx): "*Closes the cursor associated with StatementHandle (if one was defined) and discards all pending results*"

Therefore, calling SQLCloseCursor will return a "Invalid Cursor State" (see [Note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709301%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

I think what you need is:

```
SQLCloseCursor(hStmt);

SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hStmt) // replace SQLFreeStmt with this
```

Comment: +1 Yes - that will certainly be a problem! Don't know how I missed that :-(

Comment: You seem to have edited your post quickly, so I can't see the history - a bad SO feature. Bit don't complicate things - once you call SQLFreeStmt, you can no longer use the statement handle, and tjhis appears to be the questioner's problem, not the cursor stuff, which I think is  red herring.

Answer (score 0):

Inserts do use a cursor. If you are doing lots of inserts, you should be reusing the cursor.
The pattern should be

```
OPEN cursor
  start loop
     BIND variables
     EXECUTE CURSOR
  end loop
CLOSE cursor
```

In your case, I don't see an explicit open cursor, so I'd guess you are relying on c++ to manage that implicitly, and it doesn't seem to be doing a good job. Judging by the code [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=696060&tstart=0) you need to fit SQLPrepare into the logic.

Comment: You say "inserts do use a cursor" - some evidence for this? They certainly don't on Sybase, SQLServer or MySQL, or if I remember correctly, according to the SQL standard.

Comment: It may me a terminology thing.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14354/chapter2.htm#sthref73
"Oracle implicitly declares a cursor for all data definition and data manipulation statements, including SELECT statements (queries) that return only one row"